# Why did my job alerts disappear?

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I previously had at least 4 or 5 job alerts defined. However, when I now go to [Manage Job Alerts](//stackoverflow.com/jobs/manage-job-alerts), it says:

> You haven't created any search alerts. You can create a new alert on any job search results view.

As far as I can tell, the last job alert email that I received was on July 11.

I can recreate them if necessary, but I'd rather not have to do that if they are easily recoverable.

What happened to my job alerts?

Comment: Thanks for the report. We're looking into this. Did you happen to unsubscribe from job alerts under your email preferences settings?

Comment: @Des Nope. All the boxes under "Jobs Emails" on [this page](//stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current#job-board) are checked (including "Job Match Alerts" and "Job Search Alerts"). I'm 99% certain that I haven't touched those settings in the past either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed, sorry about that. We had a bug that set your alerts to "unsubscribed." You should see your alerts under [Manage Job Alerts](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/manage-job-alerts). Let us know if you run into anything else.

Comment: Yep, they're back. Thanks!

Comment: (Additionally, I've now confirmed that the alerts are active: I just got a job alert email.)